# Second action call taking old store data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am a beginner in Javascript and Reactjs. I was trying to call multiple actions when a button is clicked. The first action updates store data and the second action takes that updated store data to call an api.

When I run it, the first action is running fine and the store is getting updated but the second action is taking the old store data and not the updated one.
Can anyone please tell me how to solve this ?

My code structure roughly is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {changeData,callApiAction} from './actions.js';

const ParentComponent = props => {

    <Button onClick={async () => {
        await props.changeData(props.storeData);    
        await props.callApiAction(props.storedata); 
    }}>
    Click Me!
    </Button>
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { storeData : state.storeData }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {changeData, callApiAction})(ParentComponent);
```

The actions.js file is like

```
export const changeData = (storeData) = async dispatch => {

    // modify Store data

    await dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_STORE,
        payload: {
        newStoreData: storeData
        }       
    })
} 

export const callApiAction = (storeData) = async dispatch => {

    try{
        // call API witht the storeData

    } catch(e) {
        // show Error Dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you updating the store state correctly in the reducer?

Comment: @DavidPrifti Yes, I am. I am displaying the value in the front-end, and it's updating correctly. The second time I update store, the callApiAction() considers the value updated the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only explanation on why this might happen is because of Redux's way of data flow. Redux store handles actions synchronously , however you are using them with the async/await syntax. In my opinion it might be related to that. So how to fix this? Redux's docs recommend using middlewares. One of the most popular packages for that is `redux-thunk`. Redux-thunk is really easy to use.

In your store add these lines:

```
// ... other imports
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const middlewares = [thunk];

// Find your createStore function 
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, // your root reducer
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)) // add this line of configuration
);
```

Now to actually use thunks in redux:

```
// Remove the async await syntax from synchronous actions
export const changeData = (storeData) = dispatch => {

    // modify Store data

    dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_STORE,
        payload: {
           newStoreData: storeData
        }       
    })
}


// New action for your api call
export const callApiAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(changeData());
    const { storeData } = getState().reducerName // Replace with your reducer name where storeData is
    try {
      // call the API
      // Dispatch a success action to update the store or some other logic
   } catch(err) {
      // Here you can dispatch a failure action
   }
};
```

Then on your React component you can simply use `await callApiAction()` without any arguments because it gets them directly from the store and omit the other `changeData()` call.

Edit: You can see thunks as just action creators or functions that return other functions. For more on redux-thunk: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to explain this!